# cmake: How to write CMakeLists.txt in order to facilitate the transplant on Linux programs to Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake, cmake-gui

I wrote the `CMakeLists.txt` file with the following file structure on Linux

```
-main
--include
--bin
--lib
----SRC
------CMakeLists.txt
------dir1
--------CMakeLists.txt
------dir2
--------CMakeLists.txt
```

`dir1/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(HOME "/workspace/main")
set(INCLUDE "${HOME}/include")
set(LIB "${HOME}/lib")
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${HOME}/lib")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "xxx")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "xxx")
include_directories(${INCLUDE} ${INCLUDE}/AR ${INCLUDE}/linux-x86_64)
add_library(video STATIC video.c video2.c)
```

`dir2` directory CMakeLists.txt similar content

`SRC/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory(dir1)
add_subdirectory(dir2)
```

**My question is**: How to write `CMakeLists.txt` in order to facilitate the transplant on `Linux` programs to `Windows`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) refers to the **top level project directory**. Use this variable instead of *HOME* for refer to directories in your project.

Alternatively, for being able to build subprojects as standalone projects, you may use [PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) for refer to **directory of the current project**. Note, that you need to have `project()` in `CMakeLists.txt` for such subprojects (otherwise most of CMake commands will not work).

**lib/SRC/dir1/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(dir1)
set(HOME "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../..")
...
```

Also, there is variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) which always refers to **current source directory** (which `CMakeLists.txt` is executed).

**lib/SRC/dir1/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
set(HOME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../..")
...
```

Comment: I added a statement that displays the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` value in `CMakeLists.txt` under `dir1`. When I `cmake` in the `dir1` directory, the value of the variable `/workspace/main/lib/SRC/dir1`, in the SRC directory `cmake`, the variable value is `/workspace/main/lib/SRC`

Comment: Your question doesn't stay, that you want to call `cmake` from `dir1`. As opposite, it has `SRC/CMakeLists.txt` which descends into subdirectories. Also, `dir1/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't contain `project()` call, so currently it cannot be builded separately. So, do you want subprojects `dir1` and `dir2` to be built separately? If so, add notion about this into the question post.

Comment: yes.I would like to do every library under the `SRC` directory can be built separately.Do you have any good way?

Comment: I have updated the answer post for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute paths, obviously. Most CMake commands work relative to root CMakeLists.txt, so there is no need in defining `HOME`.

Comment: How can we set the relative path, if `set (XX, ".. /../include")`,`${XX}/YY` would be an illegal path.The implementation of `cmake` will not find the corresponding header file.

Comment: @HST Did you tried that? There is no reason why this shouldn't work.